# How to copy qwindows.dll into platforms target subfolder?

Tags: qt, cmake

I am trying to copy `qwindows.dll` from qt library folder to target one. At the moment I am using the following code:

```
add_custom_command (TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```

It works, but it copies the file in the target directory. I need to copy the file inside a `platforms` subfolder, and I don't know what to do. I've tried

```
add_custom_command (TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/platforms/qwindows.dll)
```

But the problem is that the .dll has another name in debug mode (`qwindowsd.dll`) so I need to insert the command two times.

Is there a way to use the `Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin` to retrieve the file name and use it as destination file in the second command?

Comment: Do you want to extract filename of the target library? If so, *generator expression* `$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:tgt>` does that.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need

Answer (score 2):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET demo POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:demo>/platforms/
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin>
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:demo>/platforms/
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.